# Is there any Control available for Time Picker in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I have an UserControl. I use MaskedText box for Enter time value from WPF ToolKit.
In xaml:

```
<StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">                  
    <CheckBox Name="ckMon" Click="ckMon_Click">MON</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckTue" Click="ckTue_Click">TUE</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckWed" Click="ckWed_Click">WED</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckThu" Click="ckThu_Click">THU</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckFri" Click="ckFri_Click">FRI</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckSat" Click="ckSat_Click">SAT</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Name="ckSum" Click="ckSum_Click">SUN</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>

<msk:MaskedTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"                            
                    Name="txt_starttime" 
                    Mask="00:00"                            
                    TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged"
                    Text="{Binding Path=FromTime}"/>
<msk:MaskedTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                    Name="txt_endtime" 
                    Mask="00:00"                             
                    TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged"
                    Text="{Binding Path=ToTime}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
            Name="txt_totalhours" 
            TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged"
            Text="{Binding Path=TotalHours}"/>
```

CS:

```
private TimeSpan FindTimeSpan(string from, string to)
{
    var fromTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    var toTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    var TimeTrue = DateTime.MaxValue;
    string strnew = string.Empty;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(from, out fromTime))
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(to, out toTime))
        {
            if (toTime > fromTime)
            {
                return toTime.Subtract(fromTime);
            }
            else
            {
                TimeSpan spantarget = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59");
                TimeSpan spanfrom = TimeSpan.Parse(from);
                TimeSpan expectspam = TimeSpan.Parse(to);
                DateTime d1 = DateTime.MinValue.Add(spantarget);
                DateTime d2 = DateTime.MinValue.Add(spanfrom);                        
                var CollectTime = d1.Subtract(d2);
                var sR = CollectTime.Add(expectspam);
                return CollectTime.Add(expectspam);
            }
        }
    }

    return new TimeSpan();
}

private void txt_totalhours_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (null == txt_totalhours || null == txt_starttime || null == txt_endtime)
        return;

    if (-1 < txt_starttime.Text.IndexOf("_") || -1 > txt_endtime.Text.IndexOf("_"))
    {
        return;
    }

    TimeSpan span = FindTimeSpan(txt_starttime.Text, txt_endtime.Text);
    span = TimeSpan.FromTicks(span.Ticks * ck_count);
    string time = span.TotalHours.ToString();
    txt_totalhours.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(time), 2).ToString();
    CurrentHVACUsageHour.TotalHours = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(time), 2).ToString();
    return;
 }
```

In light of the Weekday determination, I am Subtracting "ToTime" from "FromTime" and Multiply it by weekday choice. I have effectively done this.

I am planning this for Touch screen sort of Device. So the Timer control should be all around composed and easy to use.

The Same Calculation I need in New Time control. Any help would truly valued. Much appreciated in Advance.

Comment: see the question agian